# Swapping elements in Array of Pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, swap

I have the following array in C (Used random names)

```
char * inputs[6] = {
  "Kangaroo my shoe", "Fly high dragonfly",
  "Philosophical Monkey", "Jumping Ape",
  "Fearful lemurs", "Tall Giraffes"
};
```

The goal is to swap the first element by the next. As in to do this

```
char * inputs[6] = {
  "Fly high dragonfly", "Kangaroo my shoe",
  "Jumping Ape", "Philosophical Monkey",
  "Tall Giraffes", "Fearful lemurs"
};
```

I have tried the following and some more.

```
ArrSwap(char *Arr[]){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    void*temp = Arr[i];
    Arr[i]=Arr[i+1];
    Arr[i+1] = temp;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance! I've spent some hours trying to figure this out, each time I do it it ends up with a messed up order or not swapping any elements expect for the first and last.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem. It should especially demonstrate what makes you think that anything is wrong with the shown code. Ideally show more than one of your attempts and the different ways they failed. Also, I do not see how "to swap the first element by the next"  describes the difference between the first shown array and the second. Please explain.

Comment: just as a general comment, I think it's best practice when writing a function like this to take the size of the array as an argument. The fewer literals you use in your code, the more flexible and easy to adjust it will be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems in your code -

1. In function `ArrSwap()` you are looping over index 0 to 5. So, when `i` becomes `5`, `Arr[i+1]` points to `Arr[6]` which leads to read from a memory past your array bounds. Which is undefined behavior.
2. Secondly, if I get your requirement correctly, you want to swap the first and second elements swapped, then third and fourth and so on. So, your code has a logic error. In that case, in `ArrSwap()` the loop needs to increment by 2 instead of 1.

So the code may look like this after both issues are addressed -

```
void ArrSwap(char *Arr[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i+=2) {
        char *temp = Arr[i];
        Arr[i]=Arr[i+1];
        Arr[i+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Notice there are following changes done in the `ArrSwap()` function -

- The loop test condition changed from `i < 6` to `i < 5` (the reason mentioned in point 1 above). As ikegami mentioned, best practice would be to pass the array size as an argument (say `n`) and use `n - 1` in loop condition.
- The logic is fixed (as mentioned in point 2 above)
- For swap, use `char *` instead of `void *` (The type of elements in `Arr` is `char *`)
- The return type of `ArrSwap()` is mentioned as `void`. With `void` it is clearly conveyed that `ArrSwap()` will not return anything.

After fix the `inputs` will be:

```
{"Fly high dragonfly", "Kangaroo my shoe", "Jumping Ape", "Philosophical Monkey", "Tall Giraffes", "Fearful lemurs"}
```

Comment: I thought that it is what they describe, but failed to see that the desired output matches......

Comment: I recommend to also mention and explain the return value default which you fixed.

Comment: `char *temp` would also be nicer.

Comment: Re "*Notice the index changed from 6 to 5*", `6` is actually fine (with `i+=2`), and `6` is what I would use. (Well, actually, I would use `n`, a parameter accepting the size of the array.)

Comment: @ikegami, in case there are odd number of elements, say 7, the loop condition should be <6. If we use <7, then same problem will occur. But as you said, in this case, <6 will be fine. As you said, some variable instead of hard code would be best

Comment: Please explain all the changes your code has applied (and mabye do not enumerate only part of them as 1. 2. ).